# How can I use isLinear with the matFormFields (Input fields) coming from another steps components in stepper?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-material-stepper

I have a total of 8 step form. I have used stepper form for this in `register.html` with `isLinear=true` in `register.ts` file. Now, these 8 steps are coming from steps module which having 8 different step form.

Actually when I used the step form like in [doc](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#completed-step).

it works fine for me.

But when I tried to call the content of `<mat-form-field>` from steps form then it is giving me an issue of `mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl`. I understood this issue. Now I am stuck at :

How can I use the different step forms under the `<mat-form-field>` (steps forms are coming from steps folder) with the `isLinear = true`.

Here is my code:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>

    <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
       <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
            <mat-form-field>
                 <steponeForm></steponeForm>// For  this its givng me error of mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl although under steponeForm.html its define
            </mat-form-field>
        <div>
           <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
         </form>
    </mat-step>
       <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
       <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
            <mat-form-field>
               <steptwoForm></steptwoForm> // For  this its givng me error of mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl although under steptwoForm.html its define
            </mat-form-field>
        <div>
           <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
         </form>
    </mat-step>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here After lots of research, I found the best working solution.

We need to refer each step component to the parent component so that `isLinear=true` work and it wont allow use to proceed to another step until and unless current step form is not filed.

For more clearance visit [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8021) and below is another example for same:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umvpjs?file=app%2Fstep-one.component.ts.

Hope so, in future this will surely help out to other developers.

Answer (score 0):

`<mat-form-field>` is expecting a component like matInput, remove `<mat-form-field>` from your code and try again.